# Microsoft Teams task module with URL not working for external url

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

[image: Manifest file]trigger a task module that will display a web page. All I was able to get is an empty Task Module with the title, while the specified height and width do not showing URL displayed.

i want to redirect the url from the api.,but api is giving a url but not redirecting
[image: custom URL is not displaying in task module chatbot]

```
           let requestUrl = await getRedirectUrlForSubmitAction(tokenResponse) ===> api call to get the url
                const response: MessagingExtensionActionResponse = <MessagingExtensionActionResponse>{
                    task: {
                        type: "continue",
                        value: {
                            title: "Send recognition",
                            url: `${request.data.value}`, //url from api call
                            height: "large"
                        }
                    }
                };
 return Promise.resolve(response);
```

please check this below code for external url redirecting

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Redirecting</title>
    <script src='https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/sdk/v1.6.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='app'>
        <header style="display: flex; justify-content: center;align-items: center; font-size: 1rem;">
            <h1>Redirecting <em>....</em></h1>
        </header>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function login() {
            microsoftTeams.initialize();
            if (window.location.href.includes("redirectUrl.action")) {
                let token = localStorage.getItem("appToken");
                let urlStr = window.location.href.split('?url=')[1]
                fetch(`${urlStr}`, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: new Headers({
                        "content-type": "application/json",
                        "originated": "teams",
                        "post-type": "ajax",
                        "outlookauth": `${token}`
                    }),
                })
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(
                        (result) => {
                            console.log("result", result);
                            location.href = result.url
                   
                            //return result.url
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            console.log("Error", error);
                        }
                    )
            } else {
                //balance
                const host = window.location.href.split('&host=')[1].split('&')[0]
                const appcode = window.location.href.split('&appCode=')[1]
                const token = localStorage.getItem("appToken");
                const urlType = window.location.href.split('?url=')[1]
                const urlStr = `https://${host}/${appcode}/mobileapp/teams/teamsShopRedirectUrl.action?${urlType}`
                fetch(`${urlStr}`, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: new Headers({
                        "content-type": "application/json",
                        "originated": "teams",
                        "post-type": "ajax",
                        "outlookauth": `${token}`
                    }),
                })
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(
                        (result) => {
                            window.location.href = result.url
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            console.log("Error", error);
                        }
                    )
            }
        }
        window.onload = login();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

manifest file

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.8/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.8",
  "id": "{{APPLICATION_ID}}",
  "version": "{{VERSION}}",
  "packageName": "{{PACKAGE_NAME}}",
  "developer": {
    "name": "name",
    "websiteUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}/now",
    "privacyUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}/now/privacy.html",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://{{HOSTNAME}}/now/tou.html"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Now",
    "full": "Now"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "for Teams",
    "full": "."
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon-outline.png",
    "color": "icon-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "configurableTabs": [],
  "staticTabs": [],
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "{{MICROSOFT_APP_ID}}",
      "needsChannelSelector": true,
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "scopes": [
        "team",
        "personal",
        "groupchat"
      ],
      "commandLists": [
        {
          "scopes": [
            "team",
            "personal"
          ],
          "commands": [
            {
              "title": "test1",
              "description": "test1"
            },
            {
              "title": "test2",
              "description": "test2 "
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "supportsFiles": true,
      "supportsCalling": true,
      "supportsVideo": true
    }
  ],
  "connectors": [],
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "{{MICROSOFT_APP_ID}}",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "messageHandlers": [
        {
          "type": "link",
          "value": {
            "domains": [
              "{{HOSTNAME}}",
              "avidanpprd.performnet.com",
              "youtube.com"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "MessageExtension",
          "title": "title",
          "description": "Add a clever description here",
          "initialRun": true,
          "type": "action",
          "context": [
            "compose"
          ],
          "fetchTask": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "{{HOSTNAME}}",
    "avidanpprd.performnet.com",
    "youtube.com"
  ],
  "showLoadingIndicator": true,
  "isFullScreen": false
}
```

Comment: Add wildcard (*) domain eg: `*.performnet.com` or `*.avidanpprd.performnet.com`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a combination of things:

1. You need to make sure that the website you're showing is listed as a 'safe' domain in your manifest for your Teams app. I think you need something in both the `messageHandlers > value > domain` section as well as the `validDomains` section in the root level of the manifest.
2. However, depending on what you're trying to embed, it might not work because the external site has to have some basic Teams integration. See [this heading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/content-page#integrate-your-code-with-teams), where it says:

> For your page to display in Teams, you must include the Microsoft Teams JavaScript client SDK and include a call to microsoftTeams.initialize() after your page loads.

As a result, if this is an external site you don't control, you might need to have your own page that you host in the task module, which simpyly iframes in the external website.

Comment: Kindly please check this link [https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiikV.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiikV.png) even though was added validDomains as well as messageHandlers same problem continues.

Comment: Did you check my point (2) above? Does the remote web page have the Teams js library?

Comment: Please check this above code i already added html file here

Comment: your 2nd script tag doesn't look right. It shoulnd't also have src="..."

Comment: I presume you're able to browse the page in the browser ok? And with no errors?

Comment: Even after removing script tag also not working..... i checked...at the same time separate tab is working fine but inside a task module is not working in my case. @hilton

Comment: can you post your manifest file then please

Comment: sorry for the delay .....manifest file added kindly please check now .

Answer (score 0):

This issue might come if the URL doesn't support iframe embedding.

To help you here you can refer the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/54.teams-task-module) and try to bind the URL in iframe like below in your page.

`<iframe width="700" height="700" src="https://www.example.com/embed/QPSaLnaU"  allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

I have been recently working on something similar.

I have a message extension (build using Adaptive cards) and on one of the button clicks, I want to trigger `Upload Document` functionality. Unfortunately, an adaptive card doesn't provide.

So, I build an separate **angular web-page**, which will act as an upload application.

**Note:** The domain of the webpage should be added correctly under **validDomains** in the **manifest file**.

```
    "validDomains": [
        "*.example.com",
    ],
```

**On button click in message extension (NodeJS):**

```
...

return {
   task: {
     type: 'continue',
     value: {
       height: 400,
       width: 400,
       title: 'Task module WebView',
       url: `https://show.example.com`
     }
   }
};
```

**For more info visit:**

[Upload attachment from messages extension in MS Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68381569/upload-attachment-from-messages-extension-in-ms-teams)